# Why is "this.var" less efficient than "array.length"?

Tags: java, android

When I watched the "[Dalvik VM Internals](http://sites.google.com/site/io/dalvik-vm-internals/)" talk, I had a question about one of the slides about wise loops. Here is two of the seven loops on that slide:

(4) for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

(5) for (int i = 0; i < this.var; i++)

and the speaks said (4) is more efficient than (5). "array" is just an Array object.

My question is what exactly does "this.var" do that makes it is more expensive than retrieving a member variable from an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to recheck what is actually said.  Slide 54 seems to be talking about (2) and (3) and implying that they are better than all of the others.  (I cannot listen to the audio stream to check what is actually said ...)

Off the top of my head, in (4) if the `array` local variable is not assigned in the loop body, then `array.length` can be read from memory once and held in a register for the loop duration.  (An array's length can never change ... and I'm assuming that `array` is a local not a field of `this`.)

By constrast, in (5) `this.var` can potentially be altered by another thread while the loop is running, so (depending on how Davlik implemented the Java memory model) it may need to be refetched each time around the loop.

But this depends on how Davlik handles this.  The Java Language Spec does not *require* the implementation to refetch, unless `this.var` is declared as `volatile`.  But whether it does is an implementation detail that could (presumably) change.

Comment: The speaker said the efficiency degrades from (1) to (7), i.e. (1) is the most efficient and (7) is the least. You're right (2) and (3) are better than (4) - (7). As for (4) vs. (5), I think you are probably right on the point that "array" may be a local variable but "this.var" is shared by threads. It depends on the memory model that Dalvik implements.

Comment: Also, "array.length" turns into an "array-length" instruction, while "this.var" is a field lookup.  The former can be faster than the latter.

Comment: @fadden - in theory it could be slower too.  In reality, the code speed depends on the optimizations performed by the Davlik JIT compiler on the platform that the application is running.  The only thing we can say definitively is that (4) is easier for the JIT to optimize than (5); see my answer.

Comment: It can't be slower.  array-length is trivial, iget-quick is almost identical but has one extra load (field byte offset).  Un-optimized iget has to go through the resolved-entities table to find the Field structure and get the byte offset from that.  The bottom line is that the array length is stored at a fixed offset from the start of the array object, so you get to skip a bunch of stuff that the field has to do.  (But as you say, with the JIT compiler, loop invariants can be hoisted, so this may not even matter.)

Comment: @fadden - it is highly unlikely, but it *is* possible *in theory* that it is slower. The point I was trying to make is that unless you study *each version* of the Davlik JIT compilers in detail, this is all guesswork.  The slides' author has inside knowledge for current JITs, but whether those insights will be valid in future versions (e.g. on yet-to-be-designed hardware architectures) is unclear.